# Raspberry Pi 2 Windows Emulation

Tags: openelec, emulation, pi-2, qemu

I'm aware of various [QEmu Guides](http://xecdesign.com/qemu-emulating-raspberry-pi-the-easy-way/) for emulating the Raspberry Pi but is anyone aware of the settings for running the Pi 2 correctly.

I imagine the move from ArmV6 to V7 borked most of the guides.

*Pretext:* Virtualisation on this instance is required due to back order and the amount of time and work it takes to modify OpenELEC/Squashfs installs.

Comment: There is a fork of QEMU which seems to replicate the Pi2 to a higher degree than the default. Windows 10 "IoT Core" does work with it :

https://github.com/0xabu/qemu/tree/raspi